# How to remove HTML table borders completely?

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I've read other answers on this topic, but after hours of trying out - I still can't find a solution.

I have a website I'm taking care of and I need cells in the HTML table head to be borderless.

Website is http://vcollection.com and the table I'm having difficulties with is this one: http://prntscr.com/ltb9o9

You can see my styles on the screenshot, but nevertheless I cannot get rid of the border: http://prntscr.com/ltbb19

**Interestingly enough, when making the table width smaller by 1px the issue seems to persist at even pixel width (i.e. 962px, 960px, 958px...), but isn't present at odd pixel width (963px, 961px, 959px etc.)**

I tried to reproduce it, but can't seem to:

```css
.linear-background-header {
 background-image: linear-gradient(#454545, black);
 border: 0;
 background-color: transparent;
}
.main-header-section {
 display: inline-block;
}
span.header-font {
    font-family: Century Gothic;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-color:transparent; margin-top:-25px; width:963px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 0; border-spacing: 0">
   <thead>
            <tr style="background-image: linear-gradient(#454545, black)">
                <th class="linear-background-header">
                    <div class="main-header-section">
                        <span class="header-font">New Products</span>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th class="linear-background-header" style="padding: 0; line-height: 0">
                    <img src="https://vcollection.com/assets/images/separator.png" style="height: 36px; cursor: auto;">
                </th>
                <th class="linear-background-header">
                    <div class="main-header-section">
                        <span class="header-font">Car Mat Configurator</span>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th class="linear-background-header" style="padding: 0; line-height: 0">
                    <img src="https://vcollection.com/assets/images/separator.png" style="height: 36px; cursor: auto;">
                </th>
                <th class="linear-background-header">
                    <div class="main-header-section">
                        <span class="header-font">Follow Us On Social Media</span>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <br>
   <tr height="5px"></tr>
  <tr >
   <td class="newprodwid" style="width:324px" >dummy
   </td>
   <td width="15px"></td>
   <td class="newprodwid"  style="width:340px">dummy
   </td>
   <td width="15px"></td>
   <td style="width:278px" >
    dummy
    </td></tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Please include your relevant [mcve] code in the question itself, don’t just link us to it and expect us to go look.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you for taking time to comment on my question. As I've pointed out, I've tried reproducing in in the fiddle, but wasn't able to.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out this is the [Chrome issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=356132). 
All other browsers work fine, but Chrome sometimes behaves like this depending on the screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

This requires a bit of CSS. If you are using a `<style>` tag or a CSS file, just use

```
table * {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I already have `border: 0` this as an inline CSS.